# Golang Custom Single Linked List misunderstanding

Tags: pointers, go

As for me it's misunderstanding about third **if** statement.
Why **list.tail.next = newNode** adding element to the **head.next** too?

```
func (list *SingleLinkedList) Add(v int) {
    newNode := &SLLNode{value: v}
    if list.head == nil {
        list.head = newNode
    } else if list.tail == list.head {
        list.head.next = newNode
    } else if list.tail != nil {
        list.tail.next = newNode
    }
    list.tail = newNode
}
```

Here is a compiled program example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Linked List Code
type SingleLinkedList struct {
    head *SLLNode
    tail *SLLNode
}

func NewSingleLinkedList() *SingleLinkedList {
    return new(SingleLinkedList)
}

func (list *SingleLinkedList) Add(v int) {
    newNode := &SLLNode{value: v}
    if list.head == nil {
        list.head = newNode
    } else if list.tail == list.head {
        list.head.next = newNode
    } else if list.tail != nil {
        list.tail.next = newNode
    }
    list.tail = newNode
}

func (list *SingleLinkedList) String() string {
    stringResult := ""
    for n := list.head; n != nil; n = n.next {
        stringResult += fmt.Sprintf(" {%d} ", n.GetValue())
    }
    return stringResult
}

// Node Code
type SLLNode struct {
    next  *SLLNode
    value int
}

func (sNode *SLLNode) SetValue(v int) {
    sNode.value = v
}

func (sNode *SLLNode) GetValue() int {
    return sNode.value
}

func main() {
    // Linked List
    list:= NewSingleLinkedList()
    list.Add(4)
    list.Add(6)
    list.Add(3)
    list.Add(3)
    fmt.Println(list)
}
```

Comment: Where do you see `head.next` in the third if statement? All it does is add the new element to the end of the list by finding the last element (`list.tail`), setting the next element to the new one (`list.tail.next = newNode`), and finally having moving the tail to point to the new last element (`list.tail = newNode`). `list.head` is not touched in that case.

Comment: I also think so, but try to use this code and you will surprised by ambiguity of pointers. I'll update now this post for you

Comment: `head.next` will change when `head` and `tail` point to the same element. Otherwise it will remain unchanged. If you find otherwise, please show your code.

Comment: When you initialize this list and add to it elements, all elements will be contains step by step inside head.next.next.next....n-next

Comment: Where could I post my code?

Comment: Make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and post it in your question. But yes, the first element will be `head`, the second `head.next`, the third `head.next.next`, this is how linked lists work. That does not mean `head.next` changes after the second element.

Comment: I think you might need an introduction on pointers. Maybe start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) or search for "pointers tutorial" or "linked list tutorial"

Comment: Look at this updated code, here is really created **head.next...next** node

Comment: Again, this is how a linked list works. I strongly recommend those pointer tutorials.

Comment: my question was missunderstanding when executing **list.tail.next = newNode** it will add element to the **list.tail.next** and also to the **list.head.next**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only reason why `list.tail.next = newNode` is also setting `list.head.next = newNode` is that, at the time of the operation `list.tail == list.head`.

In your code, though I only see that head equals tail, only if the list has one element.

Comment: You're welcome, Note that because of that the middle `else if list.tail == list.head` statement is obsolete.